# How to track number of clicks of a button in Fabric analytics

Tags: android, event-tracking, google-fabric

I'm using fabrics in my app, I'm getting crash reports and user activities in my app, but I want to track a event example button click event in android.
How many times the button is clicked in a session for android.

can I get these details using Fabric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `logCustom` in Answer.

For custom events

```
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("myButtonClicked"));
```

For Custom events with attributes:

```
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("myButtonClicked")
      .putCustomAttribute("Param1", "XXXX")
      .putCustomAttribute("Param2", "YYY"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look here
[fabric->answer events](https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/answers-events.html?highlight=evens)